# Grails 2.1 Unit Testing Command Object mockForConstraintsTests not working?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, constraints

I have used manually written as well as Grails generated Unit tests for this command object:

```
   package myapp

    @grails.validation.Validateable
    class SearchCommand {
       String basisBuild
       String buildToSearch

       static constraints = {
          basisBuild(blank: false)
       }
    }
```

After having my hand written unit test fail I used Grails:

```
create-unit-test  myapp.SearchCommand
```

I filled in the Unit Test, and made an assertion that **should pass** per documentation on mocked constraints:

```
package myapp
import static org.junit.Assert.*

import grails.test.mixin.*
import grails.test.mixin.support.*
import org.junit.*

@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
class SearchCommandTests {

    void setUp() {
        mockForConstraintsTests(SearchCommand)
    }

    void tearDown() {
        // Tear down logic here
    }

    void testSomething() {
        SearchCommand commandUnderTest = new SearchCommand()

        commandUnderTest.validate(basisBuild: "")

        assertEquals "blank", commandUnderTest.errors['basisBuild']
    }
}
```

**Why am I getting this failure?**

```
grails> test-app
| Running 9 unit tests... 9 of 9
| Failure:  testSomething(com.siemens.soarian.sf.gap.SearchCommandTests)
|  java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<blank> but was:<null>
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:93)
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe I found the grails supported way to unit test Command objects in grails 2.0.  You need to use mockCommandObject provided by the ControllerUnitTestMixin.

Credit to Erik

http://www.jworks.nl/2012/04/12/testing-command-objects-in-grails-2-0/

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Using `validate()` appropriately and `mockForConstraintsTest` should work if the patch mentioned in the existing [Grails bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9162) is in place (Thanks to @codelark for bringing that up). In order to test the command object from a Web App standpoint (using `controller`) the below information would be helpful.

**Test Command Object Using Controller action**:-

A `command` object is only deemed as such when it is used as a parameter in one of the `action` method inside a `controller`. Refer [Command Objects](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects) (Warning NOTE).
Use `SearchCommand` in an action method, you should be able to `assertEquals`.

**Sample:**

```
void testSomething() {
        YourController controller = mockController(YourController) //Or instantiate
        SearchCommand commandUnderTest = new SearchCommand ()
        //Note the usage here. validate() does not take parameters
        commandUnderTest.basisBuild = ''
        commandUnderTest.validate()

        //Call your action
        controller.searchCommandAction(commandUnderTest)

        assert response.text == 'Returned'
        assertEquals "blank", commandUnderTest.errors['basisBuild']
    }
```

**YourController's action:-**

```
def searchCommandAction(SearchCommand sc){
    render "Returned"
}
```

**Note:**

With out the patch from the grails bug we see the below error in @Grails 2.1.4, 2.2.0 & 2.2.1

I get an error when I only correct the `validation` and use `mockForConstraintTests` without using `controller` `action`:

[image]

Comment: I hope my edit would help. I am curious to know how can it behave differently. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `validate` method incorrectly. You never set the field on the class, so the field is null, not blank. Try changing your test as follows:

```
void testSomething() {
    SearchCommand commandUnderTest = new SearchCommand()
    commandUnderTest.basisBuild = ""

    assertFalse commandUnderTest.validate()
    assertEquals 'blank', commandUnderTest.errors['basisBuild']
}
```

**Edit:** There is also a [grails bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9162) when testing command classes that use the `@Validatable` annotation. There are some workarounds in the bug commentary.

Comment: I have already mentioned about the `validate()` method correction in my answer. Moreover, in Grails 2.x `mockForConstraintsTests` has to be either replaced by `mockDomainObject` (from `ControllerUnitTestMixins`) or instantiate (as shown in my answer). Following the fix proposed by you, would get an `assertion` failure in `assertFalse commandUnderTest.validate()`.

Comment: This was extracted from a working example in grails 2.2.1. Why do you say `mockForConstraintsTest` must be replaced in 2.x? It is still in the non-deprecated testing API [See Javadoc](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/test/mixin/support/GrailsUnitTestMixin.html)

Comment: I am trying to prove myself wrong following you but it never worked for me in 2.1.4, 2.2.0 and 2.2.1. Created a brand new project, created the command object, created the test, ran the test. Enlighten me. :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/zZRKhC06 - contains the two files you need to create after a grails create-app. Then `grails test-app :unit`

Comment: @dmahapatro It appears the difference in our results is due to an unresolved grails bug. [See here.](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9162) Apparently there is an interaction problem between the annotation and the mock helper. Notice my code in the pastebin did *not* use the annotation. I'll update my answer with the additional detail.

Comment: The bug does not affect version 2.2 though.On the other hand, If you add `@Validateable`, you would see the same result as I do which I think is valid. The definition of command object is tightly coupled to a `controller`. Plus, `FooCommand` in your app is nothing but a POGO and is not a command object until attached to controller. Also refer (8.6 Applying Validation to Other Classes) from http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/validation.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28533/discussion-between-codelark-and-dmahapatro)