# grails validate nested command object not working

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-validation, command-objects

I'm using grails 2.2.1 and attempting to validate a nested command structure. Here is a simplified version of my command objects:

```
@Validateable
class SurveyCommand {

    SectionCommand useful
    SectionCommand recommend

    SurveyCommand() {
        useful = new SectionCommand(
                question: 'Did you find this useful?',
                isRequired: true)
        recommend = new SectionCommand(
                question: 'Would you recommend to someone else?',
                isRequired: false)
    }
}

@Validateable
class SectionCommand {
    String question
    String answer
    boolean isRequired

    static constraints = {
        answer(validator: answerNotBlank, nullable: true)
    }

    static answerNotBlank = { String val, SectionCommand obj ->
        if(obj.isRequired) {
            return val != null && !val.isEmpty()
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to validate an instance of `SurveyCommand` it always returns `true` no matter the section values and my custom validator in `SectionCommand` (`answerNotBlank`) is never called. From the grails documentation, it seems that [this kind of nested structure is supported](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/validate.html) (`deepValidate` defaults to true). However, maybe this rule only applies to domain objects and not Command objects? Or am I just missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a custom validator to your main command object

```
@Validateable
class SurveyCommand {

    SectionCommand useful
    SectionCommand recommend

    static subValidator = {val, obj ->
        return val.validate() ?: 'not.valid'
    }

    static constraints = {
        useful(validator: subValidator)
        recommend(validator: subValidator)
    }

    SurveyCommand() {
        useful = new SectionCommand(
            question: 'Did you find this useful?',
            isRequired: true)
        recommend = new SectionCommand(
            question: 'Would you recommend to someone else?',
            isRequired: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: nice! works great, however is there a more DRY way instead of explicitly defining a constraint for each sub property?

Answer (score 6):

For Grails 2.3 and later I've found that the [Cascade Validation Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/cascade-validation) solves this problem nicely. It defines a new validator type called cascade which does exactly what you'd expect. Once installed your example would become:

```
class SurveyCommand {
    ...

    static constraints = {
        useful(cascade: true)
        recommend(cascade: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: The only available version right now is: `compile ":cascade-validation:0.1.4"`

Comment: When running a unit test, the cascade constraint isn't registered with grails. To work around this issue, the following code must be added to the setup() method of the test: `ConstrainedProperty.registerNewConstraint(CascadeValidationConstraint.NAME, CascadeValidationConstraint)`. Source: https://github.com/rmorrise/grails-cascade-validation

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to test `validation` from `unit` tests using `mockForConstraintsTest()` then you should register the `command` objects in`Config.groovy` instead of using `@Validateable` because of an existing [Grails Bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9162). Refer this [SO question/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108556/grails-2-1-unit-testing-command-object-mockforconstraintstests-not-working/16110864#16110864) for details.

You can register the validateable class as below in `Config.groovy`

```
grails.validateable.classes = 
           [yourpackage.SurveyCommand, yourpackage.SectionCommand]
```

Comment: it *seems* to work fine (in 2.2.1) to test a `@Validatable` command class's `.validate()` method by simply calling `mockCommandObject` before instantiating it, e.g. `mockCommandObject SurveyCommand`

Comment: Agree. That was my approach to the SO question/answer I mentioned earlier. `mockCommandObject` works but `mockForConstraintsTest` fails.

Comment: ah, got it, thanks for clarifying. Obviously I didn't read close enough